# Как узнать на сколько похожи содержание текстовых полей mysql друг на друга?

Tags: mysql, match, полнотекстовый-поиск

Есть база в которую записываются письма других людей. При появлении нового письма нужно узнать не похоже ли оно на другие присутствующие в базе и на сколько процентов совпадение. Письма находятся в типе поля TEXT. Я так понимаю можно как-то через MATCH, но все примеры только для поиска одной фразы в тексте, а мне надо целый текст сравнить с другими текстами. Поделитесь пожалуйста идеями.

Comment: Может SOUNDEX()?

Comment: @cyadvert Уж точно не soundex, он выдает некие уровень созвучия. Но этот уровень жестко привязан к первой букве слова и вообще он имеет смысл только при работе с одним словом

Comment: @Алексей А match и предназначен для поиска одной фразы, на то он и полнотекстовый _поиск_. Думаю в mysql нет готовых средств для решения вашей задачи. Она вообще нетривиальна.

Comment: не обязательно средствами mysql -можно php, еслиб знать как

Comment: Ну да, с SOUNDEX() это я не подумав ляпнул... Если можно средствами PHP, тогда можно создать массив слов исходного текста (слова - ключи массива; сколько раз встречаются - значения) и сравнивать его с таким же массивом других текстов.. `array_key_intersect` может очень помочь... Как идея, народ?

Comment: @Алексей Возможно стоит покопать в сторону алгоритмов расчета неточных контрольных сумм используемых DCC, Razor2, Pyzor. Правда я не изучал этот вопрос глубоко. И даже не знаю, на сколько различные почтовые сообщения они способны ловить

Comment: @cyadvert В идее с наборами слов что то есть. правда надо с ней еще  что то делать. загружать для сравнения в php _все_ прошедшие ранее сообщения и разбиение на слова будет мягко говоря тормозить.

Comment: Попробовал простым запросом, по уже разложенному индексу по словам сравнить текст к одному объекту в БД со всеми остальными объектами с выводом кол-ва одинаковых слов. Слов в описании объекта 50, объектов в базе 14к, слов во всех описаниях 1кк. Максимальное совпадение 13 слов. Запрос длился 0.64 секунды. А писем в небольшой почтовой системе 100к в месяц. так что поиск пословного совпадения в лоб очень дорогая операция выйдет.

Comment: array_key_intersect - наверное интересно, только не понятно что делать с полученным массивом одних и тех же пересекающихся слов? складывать значения и на этом вычислять какбы процент совпадения?

Comment: >>Попробовал простым запросом, по уже разложенному индексу по словам сравнить текст к одному объекту в БД ...    А как пробовал ? Напиши запрос пожалуйста.